# Does a flex item not need to be an explicit element inside flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

```
<!-- HTML -->
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      My awesome website
    </div>
  </body>

/* CSS */
.header {
  height: 72px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px; 
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-left: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I'm attempting to vertically align the text, "My awesome website", inside the div using flexbox model.

What I understand about flexbox is that the flex container and flex item need to be parent and direct child elements, respectively. Setting `display: flex` turns `header` div into a flex container and setting `align-items: center` will center the flex items.

However, I noticed that "My awesome website" does not need to be an EXPLICIT child element in order for flexbox to treat it as a flex item and apply flex properties to it.

For example, I thought the code needed to look like the following in order for flex properties to apply:

```
<!-- HTML -->
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div>
        My awesome website
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Do flex container and flex items not always need to be explicit parent and direct child elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each **contiguous sequence of child text runs is wrapped in an anonymous block container flex item**.

The browser will create an "anonymous block container" for the text and this *invisible* block will become the flex item.

But I highly recommend you to manually put your text inside a container because **you should never make a text container a flexbox container.**

Here is an example of a bad result:

```css
.header {
  height: 72px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    My   <strong>awesome</strong>   website
</div>

<div class="header">
    <div>My   <strong>awesome</strong>   website</div>
</div>
```

I wrote a small article to explain this little quirk: https://dev.to/afif/never-make-your-text-container-a-flexbox-container-m9p